# Is there a way to load code igniter in an external file

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I have a problem with a flash call and I need to debug, before messing with the code I was wondering if it's possible to load the whole CI environment inside a xxx.php file.

Basically I would need to do this:

```
$CI->controller->method();
```

and only that, nothing should be loaded automagically, the thing is that once loaded the controller should be able to "see" all the models, libraries and config files.

Basically what I want is to be able to call CI forcing to load a specific controller->method.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

I have been able to achieve this. If anybody stumbles upon this question and needs to do this, here is the file: http://www.0plus1.com/stackoverflow/CIHack.php

Comment: Can't download that PHP file, because its on your server it executes rather than giving us access to the code... can you put it in a zip maybe?

Answer (score -1):

I would just include the index.php file that comes with CI as this run's the whole framework!

```
<?php
include("index.php");
$CI->controller->method();
?>
```

Comment: This solution can't work because as soon as you fire codeigniter it loads the default controller as specified in the routes files, other than that the $CI call doesn't work at all.